# Mysql:Extract substring from string

Tags: mysql

How to extract substring from a string like

`utm_term=beat%20complaint`

Expected Result: `beat complaint`

`utm_term=customer%20care`

Expected Result: `customer care`

Comment: How to remove %20 from keyword

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

The function you are looking for is `REPLACE`

```
 SELECT REPLACE('utm_term', '%20', ' ');
```